# SpringFox Swagger and LocalTime

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

Anybody knows how to format LocalTime in Springfox? Converting to ISO format works for LocalDate with this setting to ObjectMapper

```
.featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
```

But for LocalTime I'm still getting this in example and model of swagger-ui

```
"time": {
  "hour": "string",
  "minute": "string",
  "nano": 0,
  "second": "string"
}
```

I have read something that swagger spec do not use time format. Is this somewhat connected?

Answer (score 6):

Springfox does not know anything about the serialization features used, nor is there a good way to ask Jackson to figure it out.

However, you can help [springfox](http://springfox.io) along by providing model substitution rules. These are basically a way to change the schema of the model that is rendered in the specificiation. In your case a date/time would be represented as a time stamp which is really a `long`.

So in your `Docket` you would add a `directModelSubstitute` to substitute the `LocalTime` with `Long` :

```
docket.directModelSubstitute(LocalTime.class, Long.class)
```

Comment: is there any better way to do this? if one is using Jacksons `LocalTimeSerializer / LocalTimeDeserializer` the long would just throw an exception